# Converting HTML to plain text that looks like it was copied from a browser using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-to-text

I want to convert HTML to plain text in Python, I hope the results to look like they were copied from the browser. I tried many libraries like [html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/), [html-text](https://pypi.org/project/html-text/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), But none of them get the results I want. For example, the following HTML:

```html
<div>aaa</div> <div>AAA</div>
<div><br></div>
<div>bbb</div> <div>BBB</div>
<div><br></div>
<div>ccc</div> <div>CCC</div>
```

looks like this in the browser:

```
aaa
AAA

bbb
BBB

ccc
CCC
```

But when I use [html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/), the result is

```
aaa

AAA



bbb

BBB



ccc

CCC
```

the result of [html-text](https://pypi.org/project/html-text/) is

```
aaa
AAA
bbb
BBB
ccc
CCC
```

and [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) just removes the tags:

```
aaa AAA

bbb BBB

ccc CCC
```

well I also tried `soup.get_text('\n')` and `soup.get_text('\n', strip=True)` but couldn't get correct results.

Does anyone have a good way to solve the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is exactly the correct result you want?

Comment: The HTML’s the structure and the CSS is the presentation.

Comment: @Adamantoisetortoise I want the result is the same as that displayed in the browser, as if it was copied from a browser into a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

As @dabingsou said

This code is the generic solution using function

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 

def print_html(html): # this is the function code
    return SimplifiedDoc(html).replaceReg(SimplifiedDoc(html).html,"</div>","\n").replaceReg(html,"<.*>","")

# let's say the html is 
html = """
<div> Hello, World! </div>
<div> By Faran </div>
"""

print_html(html)
```

The result will be

```
Hello, World!
By Faran
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<div>aaa</div> <div>AAA</div>
<div><br></div>
<div>bbb</div> <div>BBB</div>
<div><br></div>
<div>ccc</div> <div>CCC</div>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
html = doc.replaceReg(doc.html,"</div>","\n")
html = doc.replaceReg(html,"<.*>","")
print(html)
```

result：

```
aaa
AAA

bbb
BBB

ccc
CCC
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Well, I want a generic solution, the example in the question is just a demo.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a general solution either. It's not easy to deal with label features and CSS stylesheets. Wait and see what others have to say